# Installing Mongodb to my EEEPC 1101HA freeBSD 9.1

Tags: mongodb, freebsd, eeepc

for days i am stuck installing a mongodb 2.4 to my eeePC 1101ha. i keep getting an error

error: call of overloaded 'abs(cons int64_t&)' is amibgous

i tried installing mongodb 
scons all --32

but with no luck.

is there anyone who could help me install mongodb to my eeePC 1101HA using freeBSD.

thank you in advance!!

Comment: http://www.freshports.org/databases/mongodb

Comment: Or if you can, create a VM with Ubuntu/etc. and install it and use it from there?

Comment: i have lots of VM already. i always carry a freebsd netbook around around the datacenter. i travel to work for 1hour and 45mins. i wanted to hack around mongdb while in a train. i thought it would be nice if i can have a mongodb installed my netbook..